Issues with Print Functionality in Microsoft Edge Version 126.0.2592.61 (Official build) (64-bit)
I've recently updated to the latest version of Microsoft Edge:
Version: 126.0.2592.61 (Official build) (64-bit)
Since the update, I've noticed a few issues with the print functionality:
Sometimes it will show the image, sometimes it won't.
It will sometimes only show half of the page when printing.
These problems occur even when trying to print the same screen multiple times without any changes and show different print results. I'm guessing there might be an issue either with CSS floats or with the print show/hide image option in this latest version.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, and do they have any fixes or workarounds?

I can reproduce the issue. It occurs when printing a web page after scrolling.
Microsoft became aware of the problem and started investigating. I think Edge will fix the issue in the future. Let's wait for the new version release.
For now, you can print without scrolling the web page as a workaround.
